# CSS lint throwing errors

Tags: css, stylelint

I am running lint and getting following errors.

```
Unexpected vendor-prefix "-webkit-animation" 

Unexpected named color "white"
```

Here are the css classes where i am getting error

```
.well-classname--progress {
  -webkit-animation: loadbar 1s linear forwards;
  animation: loadbar 1s linear forwards;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  // margin-right: 1px;
}

.well-classname--progress:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}
```

Any idea why i am getting those lint errors?

Comment: Lint helps to keep on some coding style. It's not an error in code. Just in the settings it's prohibited.

Comment: I see. But how can i fix them. i cant move forward without fixing them :(

Comment: Just disable it. If you are using some IDE from JetBrains then go to settings and find `Lint` it will show you results where you could disable you want or change the rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unexpected vendor-prefix "-webkit-animation"

This is [value-no-vendor-prefix](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/value-no-vendor-prefix/) stylelint rule.

You can avoid including vendor-prefixed properties by using [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer).

Or just disable this rule.

> Unexpected named color "white"

This is [color-named](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/color-named/) rule set to "never".

You can either set it to "always-where-possible", if you want to always use named colors, either replace `white` with `#fff` (preferable).

Comment: Thanks. I actually end up doing the same thing. will still mark your answer as answer :)